# Alternative to using the Bonjour protocol for iPhone peer to peer

Tags: iphone, networking, p2p, bonjour

I am implementing an iPhone/iPad app that allows users to send each other messages using the bonjour protocol. Basically, a server publishes his service over bonjour and the clients connected to the same wifi can discover his service and connect to it to start sending messages. The problem I've found is that some routers seem to have problems with Bonjour. When running my app at home or at some other places it works perfectly. The publishing and discovering of the bonjour services works flawlessly. However when I tried my app at one of my friend's apartments, some (not all) of the clients were not able to discover the published bonjour service. I also noticed that other apps that use Bonjour (such as Apple's Remote app) were also having trouble on said network. After doing some digging I've found that other people have had similar problems with bonjour and some routers. Therefore I have 2 questions:

1) Does anyone know if this problem with Bonjour that some routers seem to have is a widespread issue? In other words, if my app relies on Bonjour in order to function at all, do I have to be worried that it won't work in 50% of the WLAN networks or do most routers not have any issues with bonjour. Obviously I can't expect anyone to know how every router out there deals with bonjour packets but maybe there are some Networking gurus that can point me in the right direction :-p.

2) Second, if bonjour is too risky of a protocol to build my app on, what are some alternatives with similar features? The features I would (preferably) need would be service publishing and discovery without users having to manually enter IP addresses of other phones.

Ok thanks for your help! I understand that this is kind of a broad question but any help is appreciated! :)

Comment: Can you check that said router has a setting to enable client-to-client communication? Some WLAN routers "isolate" clients from each other. As for how widespread this is -- there are quite a few routers with this functionality. Other service discovery protocols won't work either directly between two clients if client isolation is in effect.

Comment: Hello. Thanks for the tip! I'll have to check it out. The problem came up with a friend's router so I'll have to go by her place to check it out.

Answer (score 4):

This is potentially a tough nut to crack. The problem causing devices not to find each other on certain networks is related to the underlying transport (i.e. multicast UDP) and not Bonjour (or mDNS or whatever else you wanna call it).

In high-level, non-rigorous terms, multicast data puts more load on routers. Large corporate and university networks sometimes like to drop Bonjour messages (i.e. UDP packets sent to the multicast group `224.0.0.251` on port `5353`) because it means the network isn't inundated with thousands of clients advertising their iTunes libraries or whatever, and at scale this can improve general performance. At the other end of the spectrum, some domestic routers drop multicast packets out of the box for reasons known only to the manufacturer. There's not a whole lot you can do about either situation.

Try running a `tcpdump` on the network to see if the packets are actually coming through. I've not come across a home router that doesn't forward them for a while. If they're not, you'll have to come up with some central [internet-facing, perhaps?] lookup facility. If they're visible, then there's something up with your implementation.

There's nothing stopping you from writing your own simpler protocol for service discovery to be sent over multicast- it's just that there are loads of Bonjour clients in a ton of different languages already written and tested.